# Database Desgin For Multiple Category

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to design database for multiple category 
Below are the tables

**Users**

```
id | first_name | last_name | password | profile_image
```

**category**

```
id | category_name 
1 | Author
2| Politician
3 | Developer
```

**users_category**

```
id | user_id | category_id
```

**authors**

```
id | user_id | author_detail | author_started_book |
```

**authors_books**

```
id | author_id | book_name |
```

**developer**

```
id | user_id | developer_programing_skill
```

**developer_websites**

```
id | developer_id | website_name |website_link
```

like same way tables will be creating for other category

Also i heard about EAV model but i am not good in database design and i tried to understand it but very complicated for me.
But this database design looks not good .so i thought of asking some help from stack overflow guys.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: @cdaiga.thanks for the comment .

Comment: I wouldn't put people in boxes like that. An author may have a website too, and a developer (who doesn't have to be developing websites!) may have written books or at least blog posts or something. So I would probably have a profile where you could have `websites`, `publications`, `projects`, `hobbies` and let each user have the possibility to fill any of those in. Of course a publication can have a category (novels/non-fiction/paper/blog/other), as can a website (personal/company/project), and even a user, although they may want to specify that they are both developer *and* business man.

Comment: @GolezTrol.Thanks for the suggestion.Here i have named website in the meaning like developer have developed multiple websites

Comment: I don't see the point of the `Category` (and `Users_Category`) table.  If a `User` is an author, he or she will have a record in the `Author` table.

Comment: @BaconBits.Thanks For the suggestion .i have added users_category to identify how many category a user will belong so it help easily identify which and all tables i need to retrieve or else if i dont know how many category user belongs then i have to go though all different category .I am also not sure whether my point is right.if i am wrong then correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is good enough, but I want to offer some improvements:

1. It's better to have a `Users` and `Peoples` table and use `User_ID` as F.K into `People` table. This strategy helps to have modular **Authentication** in your project.
2. You can not gather all category tables (Author ,developer ,accountant,business man etc.) in one table. They have different attributes. **But**, they maybe have **common attributes**. So you can use a `People_Categories` table to add all categories of a people. Then you can use `People_Categories`'s `ID` as F.K in all category tables (Author ,developer ,accountant,business man etc.).
3. On the other hand, `users_category` table is similar to not useful. To save their data in useful way, your `Category` table's `ID` can be use as F.K in `People_Categories`.

Finally see the ER below as I described:

[image]

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani.Thanks for the answer.